# Statements has no effect (if/else) in PS

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a script that gets executed only if X account is found, but is not working as intended the if/else statements get bypassed and the code gets executed anyways. What am i doing wrong?

```
$Account = "XXXX"
Get-LocalUser -name $Account

if (($Account) -eq $true)  {
 } else {
Write-host -foreground cyan "I found it" 
}
exit
```

If i ran the script as is it will output the text on the console even tho "XXX" account is not present, could something like that can be done?

Comment: You are setting `$Account` to a string, and then testing if it is `$true`. PowerShell considers a non-empty string to be `$true` (it's not empty). Think about your approach a little bit more: What are you really asking the `if` statement to evaluate?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I wasn't aware of those concepts my apologize I'm still learning and actively trying to better myself. let me go back and analyze it again.

Comment: Read your code. You don't really want to know if a string is `$true`, right? Presumably, you want to know whether the username specified in `$Account` exists or not. (Hint: Where are you asking PowerShell to do that?)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart You planted a seed now I'm left to figure it out which is what i wanted. I'll get back to you thanks!!

Comment: You will also want to read on [try / catch / finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.2). A user that could not be found will produce an error, which you want to __catch__.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$Account = "XXXX"
$AccountObject=Get-LocalUser -name $Account -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if (($AccountObject))  {
  Write-host -foreground cyan "I found it" 
} else {
  Write-host -foreground cyan "No luck"
}
```

The issue with the sniplet provided - the return of **Get-LocalUser** was not used. Instead you were using a string value which is always set therefore true - as you set it to 'XXXX' in your first line.

Comment: Checking a property is actually unnecessary. `if ($AccountObject)` is sufficient because it will either have an object or be `$null`. The former is always true and the latter is always false.

Comment: Thanks @carrvo modified the code according to your comment

Answer (score 1):

As Bill_Stewart explains, the reason that the `else` block is reached is because `($Account) -eq $true` evaluates to `$false` unless the account name is `"true"`.

In order to test whether `Get-LocalUser` succeeded or failed to retrieve the user account, you can instead inspect the `$?` automatic variable - it will have a value of `$false` only if the previous command threw an error:

```
$AccountName = "nonExistingUser"

# Try to fetch existing user account, don't show any errors to the user
$UserAccount = Get-LocalUser -Name $AccountName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Test if the call was successful
if($?) {
    Write-Host "Found account named '$AccountName'!" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $UserAccount
} else {
    Write-Host "No account named '$AccountName' was found ..." -ForegroundColor Magenta
}
```

Comment: The `$?` is actually unnecessary. `if ($UserAccount)` will be true if `$UserAccount` has an object (aka, `Get-LocalUser` found and returned the user); otherwise, when `$null`, it will be false anyway.